# V8 native syntax in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, v8

Nodejs has special flag `--allow-natives-syntax`. Is it possible to pass such thing to Google Chrome? Or maybe devtools provide some other way to access such information?

```
// running node with `--allow-natives-syntax` flag

var obj = { a: true, b: false };
console.log(%HasFastProperties(obj)); // true (Fast mode)
delete obj.a;
console.log(%HasFastProperties(obj)); // false (Dictionary mode)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can pass that flag to Google Chrome if you start Chrome with `--js-flags="--allow-natives-syntax"`.

(I should point out that you should not generally run Chrome with that flag turned on; use it only for debugging of websites you trust.)

Comment: Great! It works! By the way, why do you think that opening other sites with this flag is dangerous?

Comment: Because it exposes a bunch of V8 engine internals, and thereby potentially gives untrusted JavaScript code access to things it shouldn't have access to. In other words, you could get hacked by malicious websites/iframes targeting this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can find all available Chrome command line flags here: https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

You might be able to do a custom Chromium build that passes along that flag. You could also hook into the Chrome process and set the value of the symbol manually. Both options suck.

Comment: Would you mind marking this as the correct answer? I am trying to get enough reputation to post comments. (Strangely, I can reply, but not post.)

Comment: I actually hoped that somebody will find some solution, so was going to wait a couple of days. But if you want, I can accept it now.